# Woocommerce 2nd image on hover not working

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, hover, display

We have a problem with a new webshop we want to put online. We want to display the 2nd image on a hover on desktop for our store. It works on the default shop page (https://www.festivalapparel.nl/shop/) but not on our homepage (https://www.festivalapparel.nl/). It has been created with the building block from woocommerce: featured item. It looks like it does not load two images per item, so it can't switch it.

In summary: it works on the preset shop page but not on the homepage using their building block, we also want it to help there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your page builder block with this shortcode bellow:

```
[products limit="10" columns="5" best_selling="true"]
```

If you want to display best sellers manually you could use featured function with shortcode bellow. To set featured products there is a star icon in your woocommerce admin products list so you could just click on it and product will be featured.

```
[products limit="10" columns="5" visibility="featured" ]
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not work and changes nothing :( thanks for helping

Comment: How do you call bestsellers to homepage? With shortcode?

Comment: page edit -> block -> woocommerce block -> featured items

Comment: When you try shortcode doesnt it help? [products limit="4" visibility="featured" ]

Comment: @FestivalApparel updated answer for the best selling only

Comment: @FestivalApparel looks good, just update it with my newest update with limit 10 and col 5

Comment: @FestivalApparel dont forget to edit some styles and set witdh with your builder and it will be perfect :) glad it helped! good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks! This is good, onyl issue i now have is the weird styling, the bottom is old one but i need those settings on the shortcode

Comment: How does the styling of these shortcodes work? just css?

Comment: Set width with your builder probably there is some boxed width set now and yes css only.

Comment: Thanks this is amazing!